# How to specify a trigger for an empty TextBox in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a style applied to a `TextBox`. The style contains two triggers - both of which check the property `Validation.HasError`. A different image is displayed on the background of the `TextBox` indicating if the data is valid or not.

I'm trying to change the style so that when the `TextBox` is empty, no image is displayed in the background. I was hoping to find another property to use in the trigger that would allow me to check if it is empty or not, but I can't find one.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Here is the style as it is currently:

```
<Style x:Key="ValidationTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="TextBox.Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="fieldWhite_check.png" AlignmentX="Right" AlignmentY="Top" Stretch="None" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>          
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="TextBox.Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="fieldWhite_error.png" AlignmentX="Right" AlignmentY="Top" Stretch="None" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiTrigger, so you can check for the value to be Empty "" or to be null {x:Null} and keep checking for the HasError property http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Styles_and_Control_Templates%E2%80%94Multi-Condition_Property_Trigger

Comment: Err, I'm such an idiot. That is really obvious. For some reason I was looking for a boolean value to check against. I think I need a coffee to wake me up. Thanks!